# Adding buttons, textfields, checkboxes etc. to an OpenOffice textdocument usind UNO with Java

Tags: java, openoffice.org, uno

I am trying to create a OpenOffice document using the UNO-API with Java.
I am already able to create a simple document and put some simple text into it.

What I want to do, i.e. need to do, is add also Forms (TextFields, CheckButtons, Push(Click)Buttons) into it.

The idea is to create a form in openoffice which in the end can be transformed to a PDF with interactive pdf-forms.

I am able of creating these with iText and manually with OpenOffice.
But I have not found a (simple or any) Example of creating such objects with the UNO-API.

So any help, hints or links (not that I haven't tried to find something via google, but maybe I just used the wrong key-words) is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for you might be to use the ODF Toolkit, with its Java APIs for manipulating ODF documents, the native format of OpenOffice.org and its descendants.

I don't know if ODF Toolkit supports the features you are interested in though.  Check at http://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/

Comment: Well I tried ODF-Toolkit (ODFDOM and Simple ODF Toolkit and some other libs (jDocument i think). Did not found anythin in the API about Forms (didn't do it very thorough though). I'll give it a shot this weekend again. Still any Comments on doing it with UNO are welcome.